# PrimeNG with angular2: how to add filter for columns in p-headerColumnGroup tag

Tags: angular, filter, primeng

Background:

According to [PrimeNG docs](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/colgroup), 
you have to put columns-header in a *p-headerColumnGroup* tag in order to manipulate them with colspan/rowspan

To illustrate the issue I've used a simple example with the following template

The filter is not working in the table.

(It's the same behavior if I put the filter directive in the last *p-column* tag, which is outside *p-headerColumnGroup*)

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="characters">
    <p-headerColumnGroup>
      <p-row>
        <p-column header="Id" [filter]="true">ID</p-column>
      </p-row>
    </p-headerColumnGroup>
    <p-column field="id" header="Id" ></p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

Is this a bug, or am I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use p-headerColumnGroup..just do it this way:

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="characters">
 <p-column field="" header="Id" [filter]="true"></p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```